# how to log request object in playwright API testing

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, playwright, playwright-test

I am using Playwright for API testing and to log request object in Playwright using the code below. I tried a few options but none of them worked. Can someone suggest how to do that? Thanks!

```
 test("create new stuff", async ({request}) => {
  const newIssue = await request.post(`http://xyz/account/00000/test`, {
    data: {
      name: "test 123",
      parentTagId: "60b2b3ce-fa32-4b65-8f71-83e9efc75638",
      type: 1
    }
  });
// await console.log(request); // not working
// await console.log(request['data']); //not working
  expect(request).toEqual(201);
  expect(newIssue.status()).toEqual(201);
  expect(newIssue.body()).toContainEqual(expect.objectContaining({
    title: '[Bug] report 1',
    body: 'Bug description'
  }));
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why you want to log the `request` object (it's just an internal Playwright object, although it seems you've successfully logged it). What output are you trying to get exactly?

Comment: @ggorlen In the sample code, the payload is very simple but in real time it is complex (including many sub-objects and variables)and has some headers, etc. So for debugging purposes make sure request headers and payload are correct. I am trying to log headers and json payload. Right now i get  output =  {"_guid": "request-context@e05ffa6e30be96f877e0ffc8d69b6a78", "_type": "APIRequestContext"}

Comment: If you just set the payload, why are you trying to check it? I feel its quite a odd scenario

Answer (score 0):

Try recording a HAR file:

- https://playwright.dev/docs/mock#recording-har-with-cli
- https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browser#browser-new-context-option-record-har

Then view HAR online: http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer/

Or using custom reporter to log network report: https://github.com/cenfun/monocart-reporter?tab=readme-ov-file#attach-network-report

Answer (score 0):

You can't access data in your cases because `request` is instance of `APIRequestContext`, not an actual request object.

```js
import { expect, test } from "@playwright/test";

test("create new stuff", async ({ request }) => {
  const payload = {
    name: "paul rudd",
    movies: ["I Love You Man", "Role Models"],
  };

  //   const form = {
  //     title: "Book Title",
  //     author: "John Doe",
  //   };
  //   const multipart = {
  //     fileField: fs.createReadStream("data.csv"),
  //   };

  const response = await request.post(`https://reqres.in/api/users`, {
    data: payload,
    // form,
    // multipart,
  });

  expect(await response.json()).toMatchObject(
    expect.objectContaining({
      name: payload.name,
    }),
  );
});
```

The second argument of `request.post(url, options)` is just an object where you add your payload. Just generate your payload before the test and validate it after